# How do I disable the upgrade to new version warning?

Tags: 12.10, upgrade

After I allowed Ubuntu on my notebook to upgrade to 13.4, it lost Wi-Fi connection. Network menu does not show wireless access points, but according to syslog it establishes connection. Also, the wireless router provides IP address to the host. I don't want to spend time on debugging and solving the problem that most probably will reappear with new update, so I decided to reinstall 12.10 version.
It recognized Broadcom Wi-Fi modem right after the boot, and everything went great, until today I powered it on and suddenly found that it is running 13.4 and all my problems are back!

Is it possible to instruct it to stay with 12.10 until I decide to upgrade?